# I'm using Rails 4.1, How do I set a new models id type as bigint Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I can't use `bigint` in my Model's id as you normally would if using Rails 5, as I am using rails 4.1

I want my model to have an auto incrementing id as normal, but I want it to be a bigint not a regular integer.

The transaction table is going to contain millions of records and migrating ids later will be a headache, requiring downtime.

I tried first to use a rails generator (like a good lazy dev)

Which gave me

```
class CreateTransactions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :transactions do |t|
      t.bigint :id
      #more stuff omitted
    end
  end
end
```

Which fails to migrate with

```
undefined method `bigint' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::TableDefinition:0x00007fe8df5c9b88>
```

I already tried modifying that to be

```
create_table :transactions, id: false do |t|
  t.bigint :id
end
```

This works. The migration runs, but then it fails to auto-increment the id. Meaning, I can't do `Transaction.create`

or it shouts at me from the db layer about a `null` constraint on the id.

Apparently you can create a table and then modify it with `change_column` but that had no reflection in the `schema.rb` so that worries me.

Also apparently, that ^^ (`change_column` on id) is an irreversible migration so I want to avoid that.

I know there must be an easy / railsy, nice-nice way to make this work.

EXPECTED RESULT:

`Transaction.create`

Gives me a new transaction where the id sets itself as normal but it is a big int `8 bits` not a normal int `4 bits`

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out from reading postgres' supported data types and guessing how rails would handle it.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-numeric.html

```
create_table :transactions, id: :bigserial do |t|
  #other model stuff here
end
```

Verified by connecting directly to postgres

```
                                                              Table "public.transactions"
    Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                       Default                       | Storage  | Stats target | Description
---------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id            | bigint                      |           | not null | nextval('ghost_card_transactions_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
```